# Determine which points in a CSV are within a shapefile polygon using GDAL / OGR in Python

Tags: python, shapefile, gdal, ogr, point-in-polygon

I have a csv file containing columns with latitude, longitude and some values, and a shapefile with a few polygons. Some of my points/rows in the CSV are within, and some outside the shapefile polygons. The CSV and the shapefile both EPSG 4326 (WGS84).

Using Python, I would like to add a column to the CSV that has as a value the polygon ID (a column called "num" in my case) in which these points/rows are located, using 0 or NA if points are outside any of the polygons. How can I achieve this?

---

The following code is my own answer to my question:

```
def check_pt_in_poly(shape_poly_fn, df, transform=False):
    trees_pd["plot_id"] = float("NaN") # Add empty column with data to replace

    # load the shape file with the polygons
    shp_driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
    shp_in     = shp_driver.Open(shape_poly_fn)
    layer_in   = shp_in.GetLayer(0)
    #print(layer_in.GetFeatureCount())

    # Prepare the transformation to ensure that both data sources use the same CRS
    source = osr.SpatialReference()
    source.ImportFromEPSG(4326) # WGS84
    target = osr.SpatialReference()
    target.ImportFromEPSG(32636) # WGS84 36N
    transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(source, target)

    def check(lon, lat):
        # create a point geometry from the given point
        pt = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
        pt.SetPoint_2D(0, lon, lat)
        if(transform == True):
            pt.Transform(transform) # Apply the transformation (above)
        layer_in.SetSpatialFilter(pt)
        # Go over all polygons & check if one includes the point
        for feature in layer_in:
            # roughly subsets features, instead of go over everything
            ply = feature.GetGeometryRef()
            # Perform the check whether point is in polygon
            if ply.Contains(pt):
                return(feature.GetField('id')) # Returns the polygon id in which this point is
        return(float('nan')) # If it's in no polygon, return NaN

    # Iterate through rows of the dataframe and add information
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        df.at[i,'plot_id'] = check(row.longitude, row.latitude)

    return(df)
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our Focused question/Best answer model operates. We are not a coding service. All coding questions should contain a best effort to solve the task, with a detailed description of the inputs and error encountered.

Comment: Yes of course this is not a coding service, though I'm fairly certain that an answer to this question would really help out a lot of people... The problem is that I don't really know where to even start, but if I figure it out I'll answer my own question.

Comment: This question is closed, so I can't give an elaborate answer, but I will try to summarize. What you do is the following: use `pandas` library to read the csv and `geopandas` to convert the `pandas` DataFrame to `geopandas` GeoDataFrame (convert lat & lon column to Point using `shapely` library). Use the [sjoin function](http://geopandas.org/reference/geopandas.sjoin.html) in `geopandas` to see which points are in the polygons. The result contains the ID and geometry of the polygon in which the point is contained. This answer is a bit simplified, but should point you in the correct direction.

Comment: Thanks, Thibauld, I will try to apply that

Comment: Can I still answer my own question? I figured it out and I believe it would be beneficial for others...